# Python x Selenium x Chromedriver error: The version of chrome cannot be detected. Trying with latest driver version

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to scrape dynamic content from a website with the selenium package.
I am using wsl with the latest installed binary from ChromeDriver(114.0.5735.90), I also have the most updated Chrome browser on my windows pc(114.0.5735.199). I have ensured the path to my chromedriver is correct. Has anyone encountered this problem or knows how to fix it?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

    webdriver_service = Service('~/chromedriver')
    webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
    driver.get('http://www.google.com/')
```

Error: The version of chrome cannot be detected. Trying with latest driver version

I have tried deleting wsl's chromedriver and reinstalling it by extracting the zip from the latest ChromeDriver release. Window's chrome auto updates so not sure if it even is a version issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chromedriver-autoinstaller` library if you are using Python. This utility auto downloads the chrome-driver that is compatible with your currently installed chrome version.

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

Then in your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Reference from - https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/

Comment: wsl doesn't support snapd for the autoinstaller to work